# How can I get rid of all the information lines?

Tags: appcode

The subject says it all. That is way too much information, and the important stuff is somewhere in the bottom. What might I have changed that all these details appear?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try new AppCode 2.1.1 build - we have improved error output.